# iOS image editor in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, image-editor

Is it possible to us iOS default image editor my existing app, like screenshot [image]

Comment: No, that isn't an in-built control available for apps. You would need to create your own.

Comment: Thanks for response, but are you sure? 2-3 ago I  see , but just now I can't find it :(

Comment: You can set the `allowsEditing` property in `UIImagePickerController` which allows them to edit a picture from their photo library before providing it to your app, but you can't access the editor "stand alone"

Comment: Thanks for you, But I need Editor like this functionality

Comment: @Paulw11 Isn't that just the Markup extension?

Comment: @Sargis You found a solution to use build-in photo editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a photo editing extension in your app to allow the photos app to do the editing itself.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/creating_photo_editing_extensions

Comment: Thank you, but this question already solved

Comment: Is it possible to launch the build-in photo editor programatically ?